# Gapps has stopped. How to fix?

Tags: cyanogenmod, rom-flashing, popup

Good Morning.
Yesterday I was excited to flash CyanogenMod 12.1 in my other Android device.
The process was the same and I did everything correctly. Unfortunately, after flashing Google Apps, the system wouldn't stop showing pop-ups like "google app has stopped", "google services has stopped". Nothing about Gapps works, even the keyboard.
I have tried to wipe data/factory reset, using CWM and reflashing CM12.1 ONLY, but it didn't work. The pop-ups are still there. Maybe there's some Gapps fragments in the system... Please, I would appreciate any possible help. Thanks

Comment: Did you flash the correct version of GAPPS? From where did you download it?

Comment: A few years ago you were meant to boot into Android (for the first time after flashing), leave it for a minutes so it's fully boot (don't interact), then reboot. If you didn't, you would get exactly the same symptoms as you have.

Comment: Since the CM version is not official, but ported, I searched all over the internet to find the correct Gapps version. I didn't find anything, so I flashed Gapps from CyanogenMod link. Isn't that supposed to work on every ROM? (The device is the old, old, old Samsung Galaxy Express)

Comment: The gapps is changed for each version of android. Try tk gapps, search it on Google and flag it on your ROM. As I presume as the CM 12.1 isn't an official update, so you are downloading a previous build of gapps, which was for 5.0.2 version of lollipop, or in your case CM12.

Comment: I found the correct one! But the problem persists! After all the popups, all google apps that I open says "this app is not installed"

Comment: "even the keyboard" - actually keyboard comes from AOSP, not from Google Apps, so the problem may be not with GApps but with something else.

Comment: I learned a hard lesson today: **There's no better way to find what is causing this error than to collect a log with `logcat`**.

Comment: Can you be a little more specific? List the steps you went through, What GAPPS version you used, Phone model, etc.

Answer (score 0):

It is recommended to wipe dalvik/cache, factory reset before and after flashing anything in recovery.

So here are the steps to solve the problem

1. Enter CWM recovery mode
2. Wipe data/factory reset
3. Wipe Cache partition
4. Advanced > Wipe Dalvik Cache
5. Flash [Gapps for CM12.1](http://opengapps.org/?api=5.1&variant=nano)
6. Wipe data/factory reset, Cache partition
7. Wipe Dalvik Cache
8. Reboot

Comment: Great website for a collection of gapps, then does it have tk gapps, it could be resourceful.

Comment: For future readers I can confirm that the above 8 steps worked for me. I had done all except the Wipe Dalvike Cache. I think that was the missing key that i was missing. I used it on a Int Note2, a nightly CM13, with OpenGApps for Android 6.0. Thanks Sharath

Answer (score 0):

A factory reset will not help,

You need to do a system wipe, then reflash CM 12.1 only and then flash gapps.

- Wipe old system
- Install new system from zip
- Install gapps package
- Wipe Dalvik & Cache
- Reboot